# PHP passing php id variable to jquery for a div slide in

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div that slides in when triggered with:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="'. $row['post_id'] .'" onclick="chatWith(id)">
```

using jquery:

```
function chatWith(postid){
  $("#chat_window").slideToggle("up");  
  $(".chat_postid").text(postid); 
}

<div id="chat_window">
    <span class="chat_postid"><?php echo $_POST['id']; ?></span>
</div>
```

I want a new chat dedicated for that item to pop up

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: remember that php executes on the server, and ANYTHING it outputs in  your script is done at the time the page is generated, and then can NOT be modified by php again. You'd need to use an ajax call to fetch your id or whatever from the server.

Comment: that is fine as the item will have the same id forever. I want the chat window to be only for that id and to display relevant info for that item in the chat box

Comment: then `onclick='chatwith(this.id)'` exploit the fact that every node in a DOM tree knows "where" it is, and you can get data from that node, e.g. the onclick event will poitn at the `<a>` tag because that's where the click originated, allowing you to get its id attribute.

Comment: I tried that but I wasn't sure how do display that out after

Comment: Where you want to pass id variable ,and what  you expect at the end?

Comment: Try following <script type="text/javascript">
function chatWith(idd){    
   $("#chat_window").slideToggle("up"); 
   $("#chat_window").text(idd); 
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="100" onclick="chatwith(this.id)">
<div id="chat_window"></div>

Comment: this worked! now how do I make it open a new div on different id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       var user_id = $(this).attr('id');
       $("#chats").append('<div class="chat_window" id="chat_' + user_id +'">Chat window for id: '+ user_id +'</div>');
       $("#chat_"+user_id).slideToggle("up"); 
    });
});
```

**Edit:** To add the new div per each id you need to add div which will contain all the divs.

```
<div id="chats"></div>
```

Then instead of id `chat_window` make it as a class. Then copy my update javascript code from above.

**Edit2:** You just need to replace your `chatWitch()` function with this one:

```
function chatWith(postid){ 
       $("#chat_window").append('<span class="chat_postid" id="chat_' + postid+'">Chat window for id: '+ postid+'</span>');
       $("#chat_"+postid).slideToggle("up");  
}
```

Comment: how do I make a unique chat window to open per each id?

Comment: please look at my code above (updated) how can i put it in there?

Comment: Replace your `chatWith()` function with that one i updated now.

Comment: $("#chat_"+postid) doesn't make sense.. how will it get that? and this doesn't work

Comment: We are adding the span class with that id so you can slideToggle it. You can even remove the line for now, since it isn't necessary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49528/discussion-between-gadgetster-and-ailvenge)

Answer (score 0):

Try with bellow code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>" class="chat_window">Text</a>

$('a.chat_window').click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: please see jQuery `data()` function, `$(this).data('id');` is right way, did you read `OP` question carefully???